# How to Unwrap only id parameter in Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose We have such classes:

```
public class Cart{
   private int id;
   private String cartName;
   private String color;
   @JsonIgnore
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
   private List<Item> items;
}
```

```
public class Item{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
   private Cart cart;
   private int id;
   private String itemName;
   private double weight;
}
```

Normally, when you serialize Item class you will see this:

```
{ 
   "id" : 1,
   "itemName" : "NiceItem",
   "weight" : 5.2,
   "cart" : {
      "id" : 3,
      "cartName" : "NiceCart",
      "color" : "Red"
   }
}
```

**My question** is how can I make Cart to get serialized by its id like this:

```
{ 
   "id" : 1,
   "itemName" : "NiceItem",
   "weight" : 5.2,
   "cart_id" : 3
}
```

Comment: You'd probably need to make a new Item class that stores cart as an int

Comment: @OneCricketeer Is there a way to do it simpler with a single annotation that has already been implemented?

Comment: Not sure how an annotation would help convert an Object to a primitive

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is to use custom Serialize/Deserialize

```
public class Cart{
   private int id;
   private String cartName;
   private String color;

}

public class Item{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
   @JsonUnwrapped
   @JsonSerialize(using = CartSerializer.class)
   @JsonDeserialize(using = CartDeserializer.class)
   @JsonProperty("cart_id")
   private Cart cart;
   private int id;
   private String itemName;
   private double weight;
}

public class CartSerializer extends StdSerializer<Cart> {

  public CartSerializer() {
    super(Cart.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Cart value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeString(value.getCartId());
  }
}

@Component
public class CartDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Cart> {

  @Autowired
  private CartRepository cartRepository;

  protected CartDeserializer(CartRepository cartRepository) {
    super(Cart.class);
    this.cartRepository = cartRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public Cart deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
    var cartId = node.get("cart_id").asText();

    return cartRepository.findById(cartId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new JsonParseException(p, "cart_id does not exist"));
  }
}
```